I get stuck when i try to install Electron
I've been try a lot. but it still not work. a~~~
so up set
npm install electron
npm install electron@lastest
npm install --save-dev electron
All of these do not work. i'm still stuck.
I wonder if it is no node or no node? But I have updated them all to the latest version
